# A question from real analysis me making doubt my basics

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was having a hard time on this

Let $D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2 + y^2 <1\}$ and $f:D\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f(x,y)>0$  $\forall$ $(x,y)\in D$ then there exists a $\alpha>0$ such that
$f(x,y)>\alpha$ $\forall$  $(x,y) \in D.$

More like a prove or disprove question though. 
[**Edit** : What changes when we consider the closed disk, $D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ ?]

Comment: What are your thoughts/ideas? Can you visualize a function from $D$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Karl i was hoping to use that 'since f is continuos on D , any open set in $\Re$ should get mapped to a open set in D  but how should i conviniently choose such set in $\Re$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x, y) = 1-(x^2+y^2)$. It satisfies your constraints and  is a counter-example to the claim.

Suppose there was one such $\alpha$. Then, consider the $(x, y)$ such that $x^2+y^2 = 1- \alpha/2$. An example is $(x, y) = (\sqrt{1-\alpha/2}, 0)$ . Thus we have found a point, for any $\alpha$ that doesn't obey the criterion. Contradiction!

Now if we consider the closed disk.

The Extreme value theorem ([reference](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Enirobles/files241/lecture14summary.pdf)) states that if a function is continuous on a closed and bounded set, then the function must have a maximum and a minimum on it. 
And since, $f(x, y) > 0$, we have  $\beta = \min f(x, y) > 0$ 
Let $\alpha = \beta/2$, and then we can write: $\min f(x, y) > \alpha \implies f(x, y) > \alpha$

Comment: @K B what changes do we see if we were to consider the closed disk of unit radius($D$). Much appreciation.

Comment: added that part also